# Running magento and varnish in kubernetes

Tags: redirect, varnish

Our M2 store is in development and we are in the process of adding Varnish enterprise.

Magento is installed in its own namespace in Kubernetes called m2-dev and varnish is in another namespace called m2-dev-varnish.

For now, I have a basic VCL just to get this infrastructure up and running.

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;

backend default {
    .host = "magento.m2-dev.svc.cluster.local";
    .port = "443";
    .host_header = "m2-dev.mydomain.co.uk";
    .ssl = 1;               # Turn on SSL support
    .ssl_sni = 0;           # Use SNI extension  (default: 1)
    .ssl_verify_peer = 0;   # Verify the peer's certificate chain (default: 1)
    .ssl_verify_host = 0;   # Verify the host name in the peer's certificate (default: 0)
}    

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    set bereq.http.Host = "magento.m2-dev.svc.cluster.local";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host ~ "magento.m2-dev.svc.cluster.local") {
        set req.http.host = "m2-dev.mydomain.co.uk";
    }
}
```

However this results in a redirect loop and I cannot access my store or admin panel.

Interestingly it is still trying to connect over http

```
10.111.2.91 - - [15/Nov/2023:15:42:57 +0000] "GET http://m2-dev.mydomain.co.uk/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```